# Deleting saved searches created via Search Builder leaves data in various tables

Tags: smartgroups, search-builder

When a saved search is created via Search Builder, a row is created in the civicrm_mapping table as well as in civicrm_saved_search table. If the smart group is then deleted via the UI, the rows in both tables are not deleted. Is this a bug?

Comment: So those rows are orphaned forever more?  If you create that exact same search does it insert new rows or reconnect to the old ones?  (It seems unlikely that it would have anyway easy way to do that but...)  Needless to say but I will anyway, orphaned data is not desirable and should be avoided.  It just leads to table bloat.  Granted, maybe not a huge amount in this case, but it sounds like a bug to me.